# How to fetch this response in one array

Tags: objective-c

this response i am getting from web service. how to fetch only cities record??

```
  Data =     (
                    {
                Cities =             (
                                    {
                        CityCode = 21;
                        Name = Cork;
                        Numbers =                     (
                                                    {
                                Number = 2349990;
                                PauseOne = 3;
                                PauseTwo = 3;
                            }`enter code here`
                        );
                    }
    )
```

Comment: whats your codes so far for this? Are you sure thats a valid json format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *cities = myJson[@"Data"][0][@"Cities"][0];

NSLog(@"City Name is = %@", cities[@"Name"]);
NSLog(@"City Code is = %d", [cities[@"CityCode"] intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code is Finally used for you:

```
NSMutableArray *arrFinalAllCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *arrData = [responseObject objectForKey:@"Data"];
    for (int a=0; a<arrData.count; a++)
    {
        NSMutableArray *arrCity = [[arrData objectAtIndex:a] objectForKey:@"Cities"];
        for (int b=0; b<arrCity.count; b++)
        {
            [arrFinalAllCities addObject:[arrCity objectAtIndex:b]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",arrFinalAllCities);
```

Answer (score -1):

the response u hav posted looks like an nsdictionary. not a server returned json. can u post the exact json returned by server? tip: convert nsdata to nsstring and post dat

Comment: Please review Question then give answer